# Batch Command for using multiple files in Converter

Tags: batch-file

Hello I need a batch for the following process:

A ton of files from sub folders must use the converter to convert filetype from .m2 to .m2_lk
without copying the files in a new folder or something like this.

For example file "tree.m2" is in an sub folder of an sub folder must use the "converter.exe"

I have tried this code but it doesn't work:

```
FOR /D "X:\XYZ\M2\ToLkM2\" %%G IN (*.m2) DO converter.exe %%G
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you simply used the wrong FOR option. You want `/R`, not `/D`. Also, The file spec should be quoted on your conversion command line, just in case there are spaces or special characters.

```
FOR /R "X:\XYZ\M2\ToLkM2\" %%G IN (*.m2) DO converter.exe "%%G"
```

Comment: @pmod - Yes, and the OP used the batch-file tag, and used %%G, so I'm assuming the code is in a batch file.

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('dir X:\XYZ\M2\ToLkM2\ /b /s^|find ".m2" /i') do converter.exe %%i
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using **FORFILES** command:

```
FORFILES /s /M *.m2 /C "cmd /c converter.exe @file @file_lk "
```

Option **/s** enables recursing to subdirectories. Read [here](http://ss64.com/nt/forfiles.html) about many file related substitutions that can be used in command section.

Comment: This looks pretty good... I don't think this is worthy of a down vote `;)`